# django multi-table inheritance: upgrade a "place" to a "restaurant"

Tags: django

The same question was already asked on SO in 2010 [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3176418/django-multi-table-inheritance-and-model-creation), with the most recent answer being from 2014. I would like to know if this got simpler with the current django 2.0. I couldn't find anything  about it in the docs.

In the django docs for [model inheritance](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/models/#multi-table-inheritance), the example lists a `Place` and `Restaurant` model as such

```
from django.db import models

class Place(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=80)

class Restaurant(Place):
    serves_hot_dogs = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    serves_pizza = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

Say I already have an object in `Place`, how can it be promoted to a `Restaurant`?

Comment: There are alternatives to class inheritance. For example, you can turn a place into a restaurant by changing the values of fields. With the postgresql [JSONField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/contrib/postgres/fields/#jsonfield), you can put extra attributes such as `serves_hot_dogs` there, as if using a document database (nosql). You can use duck typing to query for restaurants. `restaurants = Place.objects.filter(json_props__has_key='serves_hot_dogs')`.

Comment: What do you mean by "by changing the values of fields" ?

Comment: That you just use the Place model, but add `serves_hot_dogs` to the json field to turn any Place instance into a restaurant. This makes the type of place determined by what properties are stored in that field, not by the class structure or table structure you chose. It's a different paradigm, so it might not be the right solution for you. It is much more dynamic, though. So you might use `serves_hot_dogs` for a bar or a sports stadium. And if you add `serves_alcohol` you don't need to perform a database migration. The JSON field is more free form than typical SQL database columns.

Comment: Ok I understand your point. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I ended up doing something along the lines of

```
p = Place.objects.get(name="Bob's Cafe")
Restaurant.objects.create(
    place_ptr = p.id,
    serves_hot_dogs = True,
    serves_pizza = False
)
```

Comment: It should be place_ptr = p

Comment: And this will break your Parent object Place by erasing its data as of Django 2.0 https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/29129 I learned it the hard way.